# What is View and Routines?

Tags: mysql

What is `View` and `Routines` in MySQL?
and what condition is the best time to use this type of database?

Comment: Routines: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html, views: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html

Comment: Voting to close for lack of evidence of any sort of effort.

Comment: If this is a homework, please tag it as such to help us formulate our answers accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Views** are *virtual tables*, essentially a way to persist specific commonly used queries into table-like structures. ([For more info see MySQL manual on views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)).

Similar to views, **routines** provide a way *to persist (and later execute) arbitrary SQL queries*. (Again, for details see [MySQL 5.1 manual on Using Stores Routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html))

Is this a homework? :)

Comment: actually no, i installed MySQL Workbench. and noticed is there is view and routines which i never use before.